# One question regarding r.v independence

Tags: measure-theory, statistics, random-variables

I just encounter independence in a Statistics course, I get stuck in this question for a long time..any help will be extremely appreciated.

First one is, if $X_1, X_2, X_3...X_k$ (finitely many) are independent random variables, and their sums are almost surely constant, prove that each of $X_i$ is almost surely constant..

I am planning to prove this question inductively, but I got stuck even in the first case, where we have two r.vs, $X$ and $Y$ such that $X+ Y$ are a.s constant, and to show $X$ and $Y$ are both a.s constant....Any help will be appreciated !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Start with the case of two variables $x$ and $y$ whose some is almost surely constant.  Give this constant a name.  Then you can express $y$ almost surely as a function of $x$.  When is a function of $x$ independent of $x$?

Comment: Thank you very much for your tip! As far as I know, If X and f(X) are independent, then f(X) is almost surely constant. So I'll let x + y = a, then y = a - x (a.s), then let f(x) = y and (since x and y are independent), then y is a.s constant and similar step for x? I am not sure if my logic is correct? (feeling missing some steps)

Comment: @MLEGMM You're welcome. Your outline is more or less correct.  However, it's not quite right to define $f(x) = y$, because $y$ is only a function of $x$ _almost surely_.  So it's better just to let $f(x) = a-x$ and show that this is independent of $x$, and therefore $f(x)$ is almost surely constant.  From this it follows that $y$ is almost surely constant.

Comment: I think I get it now. Let f(x) = a - x, the only thing I need to show now is to show it is independent of x. But we know that y is almost surely equal to f(x), then P(f(X) in A, X in B) = P(y in A, x in B) = P(y in A)*P(x in B) = P(f(X) in A)*P(x in B), for any A,B in B(R), then we are done. Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: Yep, you got it.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Another hint (somewhat different to that of @TrevorWilson): Let $S_k = \sum_{\ell = 1}^k X_\ell$. If $S_k$ is almost surely constant, then $\mathbb{V} S_k = 0$. So under what conditions will $\mathbb{V} S_k = 0$?

Comment: Thank you for your hint, but unfortunately, as a political science major, I just encountered statistics and we have not covered variance property yet, but I will keep it in mind and come back to your hint after I learn it in the near future!